# Abnormal output when using proj4 to transform latlong to UTM

Tags: c++, proj

Following code is tring to transfer latlong to utm for one location point in Japan. However, the utm result is totally abnormal as follow. Could someone help on this? Give an example is better. Thanks.
*****0.607968        2.438016        -14*****

```
   #include "proj_api.h"
   #include "stdio.h"
   main(int argc, char **argv) {
        projPJ pj_utm, pj_latlong;
        double x = 34.8;
        double y = 138.4;

        if (!(pj_utm = pj_init_plus("+proj=utm +zone=54 +ellps=WGS84")) ){
                       printf("pj_init_plus error");
           exit(1);
           }
        if (!(pj_latlong = pj_init_plus("+proj=latlong +ellps=WGS84")) ){
                       printf("pj_init_plus error");
           exit(1);
           }

           x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
           y *= DEG_TO_RAD;
          int  p = pj_transform(pj_latlong, pj_utm, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL );
           printf("%.2f\t%.2f\n", x, y);
        exit(0);
   }
```

Comment: And what values would you *expect* to get?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that you were not checking the error code on `pj_transform`, so I caught it and checked it myself.

It was returning `-14`. Negative return codes usually indicate errors.

Some digging in the PROJ.4 documentation revealed that the `pj_strerrno` function returns the error message associated with an error code. Accordingly, I used the function and discovered that `-14` means `latitude or longitude exceeded limits`.

I checked your code and discovered this:

```
double x = 34.8;
double y = 138.4;
```

Clearly, `y` should be in the range `[-90,90]`. You have mis-named your coordinates.

Correctly naming your coordinates produces the result `262141.18N 3853945.50E`, as expected.

My code is below:

```
//Compile with: gcc cheese.cpp -lproj
#include <proj_api.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  projPJ pj_latlong, pj_utm;
  double y = 34.8;
  double x = 138.4;

  if (!(pj_latlong = pj_init_plus("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) ){
    printf("pj_init_plus error: longlat\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (!(pj_utm = pj_init_plus("+proj=utm +zone=54 +ellps=WGS84")) ){
    printf("pj_init_plus error: utm\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
  y *= DEG_TO_RAD;
  int p = pj_transform(pj_latlong, pj_utm, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL );
  printf("Error code: %d\nError message: %s\n", p, pj_strerrno(p));
  printf("%.2fN\t%.2fE\n", x, y);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, In PROJ.4 code, `pj_free` should be called on all propPJ objects when you're done with them. If you were to use this code in a longer program you would run into memory leaks otherwise.